# How to fix the next checkbox function?

Tags: jquery, html

In the code below, I want to ensure that if the checkbox is checked, the variable `mp3` will contain the URL of a MP3 file, and if the checkbox is not checked, it won't.

My code looks like:

```js
function audio(){
var checkBox = document.getElementById("audio");

if(checkBox.checked == true){

var mp3 = ('https://ia800503.us.archive.org/8/items/futuresoundfx-98/futuresoundfx-13.mp3');

var audio = new Audio('#mp3');
audio.play();

}else{

var mp3 = ('');

var audio = new Audio('#mp3');
audio.play();

}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="audio" onclick="audio()">

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the `audio` variable does not get the url from `mp3`.

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question. So please see and tell me my mistake.

```js
function audio() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("audio");

var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = 'https://ia800503.us.archive.org/8/items/futuresoundfx-98/futuresoundfx-13.mp3';

if (checkBox.checked) {
audio.play();

} else {
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="audio" onchange="audio()">

</body>
</html>
```

```js
function audio() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("audio");

if (checkBox.checked) {

console.log("Audio will be played");

}
else 
{
console.log("Audio won't be played");
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="audio" onchange="audio()">

</body>
</html>
```

If you want both try this.

```js
function audio() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("audio");

var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = 'https://ia800503.us.archive.org/8/items/futuresoundfx-98/futuresoundfx-13.mp3';

if (checkBox.checked) {
audio.play();

console.log("Audio will be played.");
} else {
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
console.log("Audio won't be played.");
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="audio" onchange="audio()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. But why I didn't received the tick mark?

Comment: I pressed on both answers, A second I'll push again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onlick=audio()` try `onchange=audio()`.

You might also want to add the element as a parameter instead of getting it by id like this:

```js
function audio(checkBox){
  if(checkBox.checked == true){

    var mp3 = ('https://ia800503.us.archive.org/8/items/futuresoundfx-98/futuresoundfx-13.mp3');
    var audio = new Audio('#mp3');
    audio.play();

    console.log("Audio will be played.");
  }else{

    var mp3 = ('');

    var audio = new Audio('#mp3');
    audio.play();
    console.log("Audio will be NOT be played.");

  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="audio" onchange="audio(this)">
</body>
</html>
```